# Disable full thread dump automatically

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse is automatically creating full thread dumps. I run any application > Run As -> Java Application Then it immediately shows the full thread dump. It only happens on my CentosVM. I did not see this on my Windows setup. Any some explain why this is happening? Also possible ideas to disable this feature!
Thanks

```
2019-02-25 10:25:10 Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.191-b12 mixed mode):
"background-preinit" #10 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1a687e1800 nid=0x5cc7 runnable [0x00007f1a54303000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
        at java.io.File.exists(File.java:819)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1334)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:249)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        - locked <0x0000000755367048> (a java.lang.Object)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)

    - parking to wait for  <0x000000075dbc3f38> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.LatencyUtils.PauseDetector$PauseDetectorThread.run(PauseDetector.java:85)

"spring.cloud.inetutils" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1a6927e000 nid=0x5ccf waiting on condition [0x00007f1a54307000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000075d9afe88> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able completely root cause why this happened, but I fixed this by deleting my .eclipse folder in my user directory in Centos and then reinstalling eclipse. I did not see the thread dumps anymore.
Thanks